# WebBrowser claims "object type is not visible to COM" on ObjectForScripting

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf

I'm trying to set up an interop between C# and JavaScript using the WPF WebBrowser control. The C#->JavaScript calls work great so far, but I can't get the JavaScript->C# operational.

I've created a class for the object:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
class BrowserClient
{
    private MainWindow owner;

    public string id = "browser-client";

    public BrowserClient(MainWindow owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void sendMessage(string date)
    {
        owner.OnReceiveMessage(date);
    }
}
```

Note that the `ComVisible` attribute.

But when I set the ObjectForScripting property in the Window_Loaded event:

```
webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new BrowserClient(this);
```

I get the following (very confusing) exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The object type is not visible to COM. You
>   need to set ComVisibleAttribute attribute to True.

Needless to say, I'm pretty baffled. What is happening here?

Update: It might be worth mentioning that I'm using .NET 4.0 on Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop.

Comment: May be you need to use `ComVisible` on Assembly level?

Comment: Nope, tried that. Even if that was the solution, I shouldn't have to do that, because `ComVisible` at a type level is supposed to override the assembly level.

Comment: I think, I know - you need to make your class `public`.

Comment: That was it! Now I feel a bit stupid. Would you do me a favor and post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Happy New Year! We're all a little stupid at times - I didn't see it on first pass either :o) And "Thank You" for the offer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think, I know your problem - you need to make your class `public`